# nextjs + svgr + tailwind - Add global styles for all svg icons

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css, svg-react-loader

So, I'm using nextjs + svgr + tailwind in my app.

I'm dynamically changing size and color of my svgs, but I also want to add "flex-shrink-0 fill-current" globally to all my icons.

I want to render my icon with:

```
<AlertIcon className="text-red size-5" />
```

and to be sure it would also have "flex-shrink-0 fill-current" applied to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup, I simply added Icon component and put all logic there

src/components/Icon.tsx

```
import { twMerge } from "tailwind-merge";

import * as icons from "@/icons";

export type IconType = keyof typeof icons;

type Props = {
  icon: IconType;
  className?: string;
};

export default function Icon(props: Props) {
  const { className, icon } = props;

  const IconComponent = icons[icon];

  return (
    <IconComponent
      className={twMerge("flex-shrink-0 fill-current", className)}
    />
  );
}

Icon.displayName = "Icon";
```

src/icons/index.ts

```
export { default as add } from "./add.svg";
export { default as alert } from "./alert.svg";
export { default as arrowLeft } from "./arrowLeft.svg";
```

Icon render

```
....
<Icon icon="add" className="size-6 text-blue" />
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding a wrapper component around the icons and pass the size and color down as explicit props, along with whichever icon you wish to render.

Then in your SVG file, remove any fill or stroke attributes so Tailwind can modify those with classes. See [Tailwind SVGs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/fill)

```
interface IconWrapperProps {
  color: string;
  size: string;
  children: any;
}

const IconWrapper: React.FC<IconWrapperProps> = ({color, size, children}) {
  return (
    <div className={`${color} ${size} flex-shrink-0`} >
      {children}
    </div>
  )
}
```